# Как в bootstrap 2.3.2 свернуть collapse элемент для мобильной версии?

Tags: bootstrap

Есть стандартный пример верстки, он работает и при нажатии на кнопку сворачивает или разворачивает `div` c `id="demo"`

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">
  simple collapsible
</button>

<div id="demo" class="collapse in"> … </div>
```

Можно ли стандартными средствами Bootstrap, свернуть автоматически элемент с `id="demo"` для мобильной версии?

Comment: `.hidden-xs` может поможет? если не перекроет тоггла.

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev Перечитайте вопрос и попытайтесь переосмыслить ответ и вопрос...

Answer (score 0):

За открытие по умолчанию collapse отвечает класс `in`.
Решение вопроса: убрать из верстки `#demo` класс `in` и с помощью js на определенном разрешении экрана добавить его.

Стандартных средств bootstrap (методов или событий) для таких действий не нашел.
[getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse)